# In NetBeans, is there a keyboard shortcut for moving between HTML tags?

Tags: netbeans, keyboard-shortcuts, html-editor

When editing an HTML file, if the cursor is on an opening tag, the matching tag is highlighted in the editor. I would like to be able to map a key combination like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> (or something) to go to the closing tag. I looked for an existing action like this in tools->options->keymap, but did not find one, so I decided to try to create a [macro](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorMacros) for it. I have found that I can do it in multiple steps like this: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (fold code), <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd> (unfold code). I recorded a macro of this, and it produced this code:

```
collapse-fold-tree caret-forward expand-fold-tree
```

Unfortunately, when I run the macro, the cursor stays in the same place, rather than ending up at the end of the closing tag like it does when I do the steps manually. I have successfully created a macro that moves from the closing tag to the opening tag with:

```
collapse-fold-tree expand-fold-tree
```

but I cannot get the forward one working. I am also having a bad feeling that I just overlooked the action in the keymap settings and am now trying to reinvent that wheel. Is this an action that is already there? And if not, does anyone know how I might get the macro to work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is an existing action in the keymap for this. It is called "Insertion Point to Matching Brace". The shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>  or <kbd>command</kbd> +<kbd>[</kbd> in Mac.

Comment: Great, thanks! I missed it because I wasn't thinking of them as braces, but I suppose if the editor can do code folding with them, then it does.

Comment: default keymap was not a good one for keyboards where ' [ ' is already a two keys symbol, anyway thanks for pointing out the name.

Answer (score 1):

There is also shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>, which selects content inside this tag.